# Find a primitive of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find for which $c\in \mathbb{C}$ the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{\exp(z) + 1} - \frac{c}{z-i\pi}$ has a primitive function in a region around $z_0 = i\pi.$ Given that the roots of $\exp(z) + 1$ are of the form $z = i\pi(2k+1), k\in \mathbb{Z},$ one gets for the residuals, Re$(f, z = i\pi (2k+1)) = -1, \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}.$  The RHS of the Cauchy residue theorem will be $2\pi i(-\infty).$ This is about the first term of the function $f.$ I do not see how to handle this. Can you provide a solution proposal or a suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not interested in any poles other than $i\pi$.

If a primitive exists then $(z-i\pi)f(z) \to 0$ as $ z \to i\pi$. By L'Hopital's Rule this gives $c=-1$. Now check that a primitive indeed exists when $c=-1$.

More details: Suppose $c=-1$. $\frac {z-i\pi} {e^{z}+1}+1$ tends to $0$ as $ z \to i\pi$ so it extends to an analytic function in a neighborhood of $i\pi $ which vanishes at $i\pi$. This implies that $(z-i\pi)$ is factor of this analytic function. The existence of a primitive now follows.

Comment: Thanks. By saying that we are looking for a primitive around the pole $z_0 = i\pi, $ is it meant to find the integral along some closed curve around that pole?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic in a deleted neihborhoood of $z_0$ then it has a primitive in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ if and only if it has  a finite limit at $z_0$. There is no need to compute any residues. @user996159

Comment: You are saying, if $(z-i\pi)f(z) = \frac{z-i\pi}{e^z + 1} + 1$ tends to $0$ as $z \rightarrow i\pi,$ it extends to an analytic function. Which analytic function is this ? Also, if $(z-i\pi)$ is factor of that analytic function, how do we conclude that the primitive exists ?